# Upload time dataset in logistics model

Tags: anylogic

I want to upload a time dataset that looks like that

```
              City 1       City 2       City 3
   Truck A      2 hours      3            1
   Truck B      3            4            2
   Truck C      5            2            4
```

So right now I am building a logistics model in Anylogic. I have set three destinations: City 1, 2, and 3. And I want to arrange three types of trucks (Truck A, B and C) moving shipment to these cities. It takes different loading/unloading time when different trucks arrive different cities, just as shown the table above.

So the problem is I am using process modeling library, with 'delay' block to set the customized waiting time. But how can I set the time exactly be conditional to the type of truck and its destination? Should I have to use 'Function' or 'Statechart' to reach this goal?

Any comments or answers will be very appreciate!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you need to add that table to a database if you haven't done it yet... there are many ways to do that either importing your excel or doing it manually for example.

Second you can construct your agents (trucks) through a database and you can have 3 parameters called city1, city2, city3 that will be taken from the database that you have constructed.

You can learn how to do it, with the following video:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AdvSDuvk78U

Then it becomes really easy to add the delay time as agent.city1 or agent.city2 or agent.city3 depending on where your truck is going.